# Embed Google Analytics sessions (line graph and counter) in page

Tags: google-analytics

I am attempting to learn how to create a pretty simple widget to embed in a web page that will show the pageviews for that page to the reader. Just want to show views over the past 90 days, but as a total number and as a line graph.

I've been fussing with the Embed API reference guide at developers.google.com, and I have managed to create a basic dashboard - but I'm struggling to figure out how to take that code and target it down for only one property and how to filter the query to a particular URL.

Am I barking up the wrong tree, trying to use the embed API?

Answer (score 0):

The embed API is not the way to go for this as it is designed for you to log in and look at your own data. You would need to use something like superProxy instead - https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy

Comment: Yep - been looking at superProxy. The one thing that popped out initially was that I believe I read that it limits the number of App Engines at 25. I may be envisioning this wrong, but the best way to use this resource would be to set up an engine for each article.

Comment: Would it be possible to set up one App Engine that grabbed stats for hundreds of articles - and then somehow create a widget that each web page could grab (and then display) it's own pageviews?